# Store Variable Of Response in RobotFramework

Tags: robotframework

I want to Store a Value Of `ActivationCode` That I see it in response. 
This is my response in Pycharm terminal. Notice that I convert it to JSON with

```
${Data}=    Evaluate    json.loads("""${Response.content}""")    json
```

Now This is my response after convert it to JSON

```
{'status': 'created', 'statusCode': '0001', 'message': {'type': 'success', 'text': 'Ø«Ø¨Øªâ\x80\x8cÙ\x86Ø§Ù\x85 Ù\x85Ù\x88Ù\x81Ù\x82Û\x8cØª Ø¢Ù\x85Û\x8cØ² Ø¨Ù\x88Ø¯'}, 'error': [], '
data': {'user': {'uuid': 'c6b65427-bbfa-4d25-ac3e-aa190d45f5d9', 'username': 'dropp45', 'phoneNumber': '09203947700', 'activationCode': '88261'}}}
```

How do I store `activationCode` in a variable for next step what is keyword to show 88261

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just go to the Json Response like this:

```
${activationCode}=  Set Variable  ${Data}[data][user][activationCode]  #You access activationCode
Log  ${activationCode}  # This will Log 88261
```

Answer (score 2):

Once the value is a normal dictionary, you access it with the keys' names:

```
${value}=    Set Variable    ${Data['data']['user']['activationCode']}
Log     ${value}    # will print 88261
```